# Which satellite channel to learn German in Europe?

Tags: learning, resource

I've a good satellite system here in Europe. I can get:

- Hotbird 13
- Astra 19.2
- Astra 28

I would like to know if there is a channel dedicated to German teaching, maybe with subtitle.

Comment: Maybe does exists some cartoon / child transmission german/english with subtitle ?

Comment: I'd recommend you Deutsche Welle.